# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise) Error StaticInjectorError [t]

Tags: angular

I got the following error when access the application using prod build.

```
main.5ad47805a2fb5449cbe9.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[t]: 
  StaticInjectorError[t]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
Error: StaticInjectorError[t]: 
  StaticInjectorError[t]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
    at t.get (main.5ad47805a2fb5449cbe9.bundle.js:1)
    at main.5ad47805a2fb5449cbe9.bundle.js:1
    at t (main.5ad47805a2fb5449cbe9.bundle.js:1)
    at t.get (main.5ad47805a2fb5449cbe9.bundle.js:1)
    at main.5ad47805a2fb5449cbe9.bundle.js:1
    at t (main.5ad47805a2fb5449cbe9.bundle.js:1)
    at t.get (main.5ad47805a2fb5449cbe9.bundle.js:1)
    at kr (main.5ad47805a2fb5449cbe9.bundle.js:1)
    at main.5ad47805a2fb5449cbe9.bundle.js:1
    at Mr (main.5ad47805a2fb5449cbe9.bundle.js:1)
    at P (polyfills.16351918cc7f68a8b4c0.bundle.js:1)
    at P (polyfills.16351918cc7f68a8b4c0.bundle.js:1)
    at polyfills.16351918cc7f68a8b4c0.bundle.js:1
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.16351918cc7f68a8b4c0.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.5ad47805a2fb5449cbe9.bundle.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.16351918cc7f68a8b4c0.bundle.js:1)
    at e.runTask (polyfills.16351918cc7f68a8b4c0.bundle.js:1)
    at v (polyfills.16351918cc7f68a8b4c0.bundle.js:1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, you are missing some of your service in your app module providers. please add it. the issue will get fixed

Answer (score 1):

I cant add a coment because i dont have enougth reputation, but your problem may eb caused by an incorrect injection. If u want to add a new component, u must add it in the **app.module.ts**.
Ej:

```
import { Base64 } from "@ionic-native/base64";
```

---

```
providers:[
  Base64,
],
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i added all the services in app.module.ts. I need to add all the third party service in app.module?

Comment: yes, you should add it in "app.module.ts " or in the other modules of your app like "usuarios.module.ts", "food.module.ts"....